# How to programatically achieve UncommitedDataWarning in ADF?

Tags: javascript, jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

ADF has this document property (UncommitedDataWarning) that warns the user when he wants to navigate to another page having some not Commited date in the actual page. This is just a warning. I want to perform a Rollback for the entered data when the user press OK in the dialog box. 
Does anyone know any way on how to achieve this?

If someone has any idea to achieve this through JSF & JavaScript please tell me that, maybe I will find someway to adapt that :).

Comment: Reading the answers and comments below, why not create a custom warning and pointing the "OK" button to a rollback? I've done custom warning boxes before, but not in the context of navigating away from a page, perhaps someone else can help with that.

Comment: Yes this is something that I need, but I do not know how to detect if user is pressing F5 or just entering another URL in the address bar..

Comment: This looks like it might be a step in the direction you need to take :) https://blogs.oracle.com/groundside/entry/ever_wondered_how_uncommitteddatawarning_works

Comment: Thanks but I found it some hours before, it just explains what happens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the code of phase listener i use it to check if the user is logged in in ADF.make the changes you want to check about anything else

```
import javax.el.ELContext;
import javax.el.ExpressionFactory;
import javax.el.ValueExpression;

import javax.faces.application.Application;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import oracle.adf.controller.ControllerContext;
import oracle.adf.controller.faces.lifecycle.JSFLifecycle;
import oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PagePhaseEvent;
import oracle.adf.controller.v2.lifecycle.PagePhaseListener;

import view.backing.UserData;


 public class SecurityPagePhaseListener implements PagePhaseListener {
      public static final String LOGIN_VIEW = "/Home";
public static final String LOGOUT_MSG = "You are not logged in";
public static final String PASTE_MSG = "Don't try  to copy and paste URL address :)";
public static final String currentView=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getId();


public static Object resolveExpression(String expression) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Application app = facesContext.getApplication();
    ExpressionFactory elFactory = app.getExpressionFactory();
    ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
    ValueExpression valueExp = elFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, expression, Object.class);
    return valueExp.getValue(elContext);
}

public void beforePhase(PagePhaseEvent event) {

    if (event.getPhaseId() == JSFLifecycle.INIT_CONTEXT_ID) {

        ControllerContext cc = ControllerContext.getInstance();
        String viewId = cc.getCurrentViewPort().getViewId();
        Boolean protectedView = SecurityUtil.isProtectedPage(viewId);

        /** ------ [ If requested page is protected area ] ----- */
        if (protectedView) {
            UserData ud = (UserData)resolveExpression("#{UserData}");
            Boolean logedIn = ud.getLoggedIn();
            /** ------ [ If user is not logged in ] ----- */
            if (!logedIn) {
                FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(LOGOUT_MSG);
                fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                context.addMessage(null, fm);
               SecurityUtil.displayView(LOGIN_VIEW);
            }


            /** [ If user try to paste direct link to protected page ] */
            if (!SecurityUtil.isViewState()) {
                FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage(PASTE_MSG);
                fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                context.addMessage(null, fm);
               SecurityUtil.displayView(LOGIN_VIEW );
            }
        }
    }

}

public void afterPhase(PagePhaseEvent event) {
}

 }
```

Do not forget to register it in adf-settings.xml as follows

```
 <lifecycle>
  <phase-listener>
    <listener-id>SecurityPagePhaseListener</listener-id>
      <class>security.SecurityPagePhaseListener</class>
  </phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/warning_of_uncommitted_unsaved_changes.

I assume you just need to switch it on. <AF:document uncommittedDataWarning="on">

Comment: Yes thanks, this is just a warning. If the user press OK there, he will navigate to the other page without problem. No rollback operation will be called. Practically I want to use the same thing as that, just that I want to Rollback when user press OK. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

ok you want to do a rollback yourself  when you press ok although your changes will not be committed by itself if you do not commit it

you can check your Application module.If the data is dirty (so there are changes had been made) you can call a popup window (RichPopup) which you made in your page and has output text tells you about the changes and a button which rollback your changes

get your Application module by

```
private ApplicationModule getApplicationModule(String dataProvider) {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Application app = fc.getApplication();
    ExpressionFactory elFactory = app.getExpressionFactory();
    ELContext elContext = fc.getELContext();
    ValueExpression valueExp = elFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, dataProvider, Object.class);

    return (ApplicationModule)valueExp.getValue(elContext);
}
```

check for any changes by the following method

```
 private boolean pendingChangesExist() {
    return this.getApplicationModule("#{data.AppModuleDataControl.dataProvider}").getTransaction().isDirty();
}
```

and in the button you use  for navigation call the following method

```
 public String gotosecondpage() {
    if (!this.pendingChangesExist()) {
        make navigation-
    } else {
         call your pop up window }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but no, this is not true. At least in ADF once you submit your changes in the iterator, you have to call rollback to cancel those even though you did not commit nothing.

Comment: edit my post with how to do UncommitedDataWarning programmatically in ADF

Comment: Thanks again but my question is for the case when user press F5 for example or enters another URL in the Address bar. In this case I want to make the rollback. Sorry if I bothered you, maybe my question is not very clear but I did not knew how to write it better..

Comment: what i understand from your question is that you do not want to use a Declarative way to check changes, you want a programmatic one so this is the programmatic method for checking changes so the answer is call the method which check for changes for any case you want

Comment: do you know how can I detect if the user has entered another URL in the address bar and wants to navigate directly to another page? I know that the data will not be commited, but if it is submited it will be in the iterator till I call rollback another time

Comment: you can use a filter or a phase listener this is what you normally do when the user copy a URL and paste it in the Address bar without logging in or trying to access unAuthorized page

Comment: Can you help me with a hint on how to use that? This is practically what I really need

Comment: see my last answer and i strongly recommend to learn more about ADF http://stackoverflow.com/a/19141444/2422368